# Future already completed after installation in terminal on mac

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and use mac os BigSur, I try to install flutter on my system but I have an error after download SDK and unzip it, after I run any command of flutter like flutter doctor or flutter upgrade in the terminal show have this error

> Building flutter tool...
> Unhandled exception:
> Bad state: Future already completed
> #0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:43:31)
> #1      _NativeSocket.startConnect..connectNext. (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682:23)
> #2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1102:14)
> #3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1109:12)
> #4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1130:11)
> #5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
> Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
> ^C%

so what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is Kaspersky internet security on mac os, for running flutter must quit Kaspersky app to flutter can run

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this answer [MacOS Big Sur and Proxifie](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68999#issuecomment-730190150)

Try running the command `flutter config --no-analytics`

Comment: that's not working try it befor but same error